# password protection

Tags: security, access

these days I have deployed a magento instance, but the webshop is not online yet, so I have added an `.htaccess` password protection to the website which indeed worked fine, but caused problems when my client wanted to upload images for his products.

Is there a way to password protect the whole store for development purposes, using magento-capabilities itself, so that logged in user has full access to the page, but not the public?

I came over [this module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-restriction.html), but it is unfortunately not compatible with magento 1.8, or I do not know how to install it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: Your answer looks very good, I will try it as fast as I can, but right now I am unfortunately bothered with something else, but I will let you know as soon as possible!

Comment: A workaround to make the flash upload work without authentication can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675004/htpasswd-magento-and-the-image-uploader-http-error (Warning: this is unsecure because it doesn't prevent access to the site, just makes accessing it complicated. So use with care)

Answer (score 3):

You can write a small custom extension that checks if the user has permission to access the site.

Your `config.xml` would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <[Namespace]_[Module]>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
      </[Namespace]_[Module]>
   </modules>
   <global>
      <models>
         <[module]>
            <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
         </[module]>
      </models>
      <events>
         <controller_front_init_before>
            <observers>
               <[namespace]_[module]_access_observer>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>checkAccess</method>
               </[namespace]_[module]_access_observer>
            </observers>
         </controller_front_init_before>
      </events>
   </global>
</config>
```

And your observer class something like this

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
   public function checkAccess()
   {
      $adminurl = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName');

      $urlstring = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
      $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($urlstring);

      if (strstr($url->path, "/{$adminurl}"))   return $this; // this is the admin section

      // get admin session
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'))->start();

      $admin_logged_in = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'))->isLoggedIn();

      // return to frontend section
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'))->start();

      if (!$admin_logged_in)
      {
         die('No access!');
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this work, @sander? I have had mixed results with trying to start adminhtml session and then restore it to the origination session...

Comment: I have something like this working on a 1.5 store. I'm testing right now on 1.8 :)

Comment: I've updated the code, this is tested on Magento 1.8.0.0